# MSG91 otp message send working in development but after build apk it didn't work in expo react app

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to send an otp message on a mobile in order to login. In development it is working perfectly but after building the apk it did not send the otp and didn't get any response.

Using MSG91 with expo react app, is there any solution to make it work after building the apk ?